# Adding loading image into the <ul> for live search

Tags: jquery

I need to add a small loading image to my live search engine (as per the photo) to have it shown before the search results comes up as I'd have several images called from database which may need some time to load, and when the result is loaded the loading image fadeout

[image]

My Script code is:

```
   <script> 
    // Start Ready
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // Icon Click Focus
        $('div.icon').click(function(){
            $('input#search').focus();
        });

        // Live Search
        // On Search Submit and Get Results
        function search() {
            var query_value = $('input#search').val();
            $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
            if(query_value !== ''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: { query: query_value },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("ul#results").html(html);
                    }
                });
            }return false;    
        }

        $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
            // Set Timeout
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

            // Set Search String
            var search_string = $(this).val();

            // Do Search
            if (search_string == '') {
                $("ul#results").fadeOut();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $("ul#results").fadeIn();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
                $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
            };
        });

    });
</script>
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<div id="main">

        <input name="Search" type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search by item name or number')
 {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')
 {this.value = 'Search by item name or number';}" 
value="Search by item name or number">
        <!-- Show Results -->

    <ul id="results" style="height:350px;  overflow-x:hidden ; overflow-y: scroll; padding-bottom:10px; color:#FFF"></ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

On keyup, append the loading image to ul, after the result, hide it again.

```
// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    // remove loading gif
                    $("ul#results").html('');
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {

        // show loading gif after keying 3 characters
        if($(this).val().length >= 3)
            $("ul#results").append('<li><img src="yourLoadingImg.gif" /></li>');

        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }
        if(search_string.length >= 3){
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You are perfect, thanks a lot, one more thing, may you adjust this image to show up ONLY after typing three letters?!.... thanks again, I was searching it two days already.

Comment: check my update answer again, add this condition for showing image...if($(this).val().length >= 3) ...

Comment: if possible & I may be bothering, I wish to make the slide down window only fade in after writing three letters in the input box, I think it is little code in the //DO Search// place at the end of the code, thanks again.

Comment: nvm, check update answer again, try this? ... else if(search_string.length >= 3) ...

Comment: You are brilliant, it worked fine but the results stopped from coming up, it only shows the loading image and keep loading....

Comment: :) remove else? just ...if(search_string.length >= 3){}...coz I cannot test the script.